# how to add space to this regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need my regular expression to have a space between the text, but not at the beginning or at the end

this is my regular expression

`^(?=.{8,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$`

i need something like this:

| Regex | expected result |
| --- | --- |
| `Abcd1234` | true |
| `Abcd 1234` | true |
| `Abcd1234` | false |
| `Abcd1234` | false |

Comment: you can try replacing `(?=.{8,}$)` with `(?=\S.{6,}\S$)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce that it starts and ends with non-space characters, you could try something like this:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Also, I recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). You can interactively change the  expression and your test cases and it will show you where the matches are. This can be very useful for debugging. See image below:

[image]

Comment: This expression passes all the test cases you provided. If there are more restrictions, you should edit the question with more information about the input and output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes one large regex containing all criteria is not the best option. For validation purposes it's often better to define each requirement separate. That way you can also provide the user with a relevant error message, instead of a large catch-all error message.

```js
function isValid(input, criteria) {
  const errors = [];
  
  for (const [isValid, error] of criteria) {
    if (!isValid(input)) errors.push(error);
  }
    
  return [!errors.length, errors];
}

const criteria = [
  [input => input.match(/^\S/),
    "must start with a non-whitespace character"],
  [input => input.match(/\S$/),
    "must end with a non-whitespace character"],
  [input => input.length >= 8,
    "must have a length of at least 8 characters"],
  [input => input.match(/[a-z]/),
    "must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)"],
  [input => input.match(/[A-Z]/),
    "must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)"],
  [input => input.match(/[0-9]/),
    "must contain at least one digit (0-9)"],
];

document.forms["validate-string"].addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const form = event.target;
  const inputs = form.elements.inputs.value.split("\n");
  
  inputs.forEach(input => console.log(JSON.stringify(input), ...isValid(input, criteria)));
});
```

```html
<form id="validate-string">
<textarea name="inputs" rows="5" cols="9">Abcd1234
Abcd 1234
 Abcd1234
Abcd1234 
abcdefgh</textarea>
<br />
<button>validate</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided input, couldn't you simplify this to?:

> `/^[a-z]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}$/i`

```js
const isValid = (str) => /^[a-z]{4}\s?[0-9]{4}$/i.test(str);

// Valid
console.log(isValid('Abcd1234'));
console.log(isValid('Abcd 1234'));

// Invalid
console.log(!isValid(' Abcd1234'));
console.log(!isValid('Abcd1234 '));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your test cases and what you seem to be attempting with your regex, I think your target is matching any sequence of at least 8 letter or digits characters with spaces in-between but not before or after:

```regex
^(\w\s*){7,}\w$
```

Matches any letter or digit followed by zero or more spaces, at least 7 times, then a single alphanumeric character, which makes a total of at least 8.

You can test and refine it here: https://regex101.com/r/xNwdRq/1
(Go to the "Unit Tests" section)

Attention: `\w` also matches the underscore `_`. If you don't want this, replace it with `[A-Za-z0-9]`